# Converting a decimal to a integer

Tags: sql-server

How can I safely convert the following:

```
ISNULL(t1.UserPercentage,0) AS UserPercentage
```

Current the t1.UserPecentage column is a decimal(9,2), I want to convert it to an integer.

Since the value can be NULL, the conversion should be done based on the result of the call to ISNULL correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Var DECIMAL(9,2) = 2.67

SELECT CAST(ROUND(@Var,0) AS INT)
```

This query will keep nulls but If you want to convert NULLS into 0

THEN

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(@Var, 0),0) AS INT)
```

**Note**

> Converting DECIMAL to int without ROUNDing it will give you a bit less
>   accurate result then if you ROUND it to zero before you cast it as
>   int.
>
> Direct conversion into INT will simply truncate any decimals but if
>   you ROUND it to zero 1st and then CAST as int , it will give you more
>   realistic results.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Var DECIMAL(9,2) = 2.67
SELECT CAST(@Var AS INT)
```

This will return 2, but basic rules of mathematics says this value is 3 if it is rounded to a whole number.

```
DECLARE @Var DECIMAL(9,2) = 2.67
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@Var,0) AS INT)
```

This query will return 3. More accurate then just converting it to INT.

Answer (score 1):

If your desired result is a simple truncation of the decimal points, using FLOOR is your best option. At first glance, it would be more obvious to other people what you're trying to do.

```
ISNULL(FLOOR(t1.UserPercentage), 0) AS UserPercentage
```

Examples:

```
SELECT FLOOR(1.1), FLOOR(1.9)
-- Result is a simple truncation of the decimal points. (=1)
```

Comment: Be aware that floor() may not be the function you're looking for... From the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql): _Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression._ In other words `select floor(-123.45)` returns `-124`, as opposed to `select cast(-123.45 as int)` which returns `-123`, or `select round(-123.45, 0)` which returns `-123.00`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @val decimal(9,2) =43.44
select convert(int, @val)
```

or

```
select cast(@val as int)
```